# My macbook doesn't "really" power off

Tags: macbook, power-management

When I shut down my macbook, it doesn't really power off: the screen turn black as if it were switch off but when closing the screen, the sleep led turn on.
In order to turn it on again I have to press long the power button (to really switch it off), and press again.

EDIT: I precise that I hear a beep when switching off (like the one when you try to quit the finder with cmd+q for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/) and run various basic scan of this application. Since then the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Shut Down from the Apple Menu? If so, I bet there is some process running that is preventing you from shutting down. Check that Time Machine isn't running a backup at the same time you are trying to shut down.

Comment: I would open up Console.app after one of these ill-fated shutdowns and see you can trace trace down the hanging process.  My old white macbook used to do this occasionally, but i so rarely shut it down that it was not really an issue.